# Kotlin - Recycleview ViewHolder OnClick not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, onclicklistener

I have an app in Kotlin done by another developer. It sets Onclick listeners in "onBindViewHolder" method of RecycleView Adapter. Somehow after the view scrolls out of the visible area (i.e. user scrolls down) and the user scrolls back to top, the onclick method only gets called after the view is tapped TWICE. Don't understand what's going on, and my Kotlin knowledge is very little. This is how the onclick listener is set:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
//...
    holder.itemView.editButton.onClick {
                Log.d("Holder", "Click")

    }
//...
```

}

It is working EXCEPT when the view gets out of screen. Also, onBindViewholder is not called for views just coming back from outside of the screen, which is not standard I believe?

There is no special settings for the recycleview either, just a simple linearlayout and a single view type.

Any ideas?

Comment: `Kotlin` does not make any difference in Android Core classes usecase its syntactically differ from java . You should post whole code of adapter .

Comment: Are you using `kotlin synthetic` ?

Comment: call your `holder.itemView.editButton.onClick` inside your custom `ViewHolder` constructor, not inside `onBindViewHolder` method

Comment: My bad, the problem might be connected to the fact that the Recycleview is inside a CoordinatorLayout. Still a very weird issue

Comment: `CoordinatorLayout` has nothing to do with it - just setup your `OnClickListener` inside view holder constructor

Comment: Then it wouldn't work otherwise. No touch event is propagated to the view at all due to bad custom layout behaviour implementation

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
holder.itemView.editButton.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick(v: View?) {
               Log.d("Holder", "Click")
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you bind the value of edittext with ViewHolder class like below

```
class ViewHolder (view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    // Holds the button that will add each editButton to
    val editButton = view.editButton
}
```

After try this simple code

```
    holder?.editButton.setOnClickListener {
        Log.e("editbutton", "onClick")
    }
```